# Replace text using sed

Tags: regex, shell, date, sed

i am having trouble replacing the modified date in my script via sed.

I am getting the last modified date like this:

```
olddate=`grep -m1 "Built " script.sh | cut -c 22-29`
```

I get the current date with:

```
newdate=`date +%d/%m/%y`
```

Basically i want to replace old date with new date

```
sed -i "" "s/$olddate/$newdate/g" script.sh
```

But this doesn't work as the date contains slashes. I've looked around and i can't find the way to escape them properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `grep [...] | cut [...]` is often better expressed using `awk` (and saves you a pipe)

Comment: In *this* case, `awk '/Built / { print substr($0, 22, 8); exit }' script.sh`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use separators other than slashes, for instance "**;**"

```
sed -i "" "s;$olddate;$newdate;g" script.sh
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for such a quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Use , instead of / !

```
sed -i "" "s,$olddate,$newdate,g" script.sh
```

In fact you can use almost any char as separators.

Answer (score 2):

use `sed "s#$olddate#$newdate#g"`

that should work